# HTML/CSS Animated Backgrounds

Tags: html, css, background, css-animations

My friend thought of this idea for me to try out but I don't even know where to start. It is basically having smoke in the background of a website. Like moving around and what not. Just a simple smokey moving background. Seems possible but I have no idea where to start looking so any help in the right direction would be fantastic!

Comment: I would place a video in the background.

Answer (score 2):

*here one not so complicated*

```
<div id="smoke">
  <span class="s0"></span>
  <span class="s1"></span>
  <span class="s2"></span>
  <span class="s3"></span>
  <span class="s4"></span>
  <span class="s5"></span>
  <span class="s6"></span>
  <span class="s7"></span>
  <span class="s8"></span>
  <span class="s9"></span>
</div>
```

css

```
body {background: #18d0f0}

/* Smoke container */

#smoke {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 1px; height: 160px;
    left: 50%; bottom: 30px;
}

/* No animations? Display a static smoke image */

.disableAnimations #smoke,
.no-cssanimations #smoke {
    width: 86px;
    margin-left: -25px;
    bottom: 146px;
    background: url('../img/smokeNoAni.png') no-repeat center bottom;
}

/* smoke balls */

.cssanimations #smoke span { 
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -35px; left: 50%; margin-left:-20px;
    height: 0px; width: 0px;
    border: 35px solid #4b4b4b;
    border-radius: 35px;
    left: -14px; opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.2);
}

/* Smoke animation */

@mixin keyframes($name) {
    @-webkit-keyframes #{$name} { @content; }
    @-moz-keyframes #{$name} { @content; }
    @-o-keyframes #{$name} { @content; }
    @keyframes #{$name} { @content; }
}

@mixin animation($parameters) {
    -webkit-animation: $parameters;
    -moz-animation: $parameters;
    -o-animation: $parameters;
    animation: $parameters;
}

@include keyframes(smokeL) {
    0%   { @include transform(scale(0.2) translate(0, 0)) }
    10%  { opacity: 1; @include transform(scale(0.2) translate(0, -5px)) }
    100% { opacity: 0; @include transform(scale(1) translate(-20px, -130px)) }
}


@include keyframes(smokeR) {
    0%   { @include transform(scale(0.2) translate(0, 0)) }
    10%  { opacity: 1; @include transform(scale(0.2) translate(0, -5px)) }
    100% { opacity: 0; @include transform(scale(1) translate(20px, -130px)) }
}

#smoke .s0 { @include animation(smokeL 10s 0s infinite) }
#smoke .s1 { @include animation(smokeR 10s 1s infinite) }
#smoke .s2 { @include animation(smokeL 10s 2s infinite) }
#smoke .s3 { @include animation(smokeR 10s 3s infinite) }
#smoke .s4 { @include animation(smokeL 10s 4s infinite) }
#smoke .s5 { @include animation(smokeR 10s 5s infinite) }
#smoke .s6 { @include animation(smokeL 10s 6s infinite) }
#smoke .s7 { @include animation(smokeR 10s 7s infinite) }
#smoke .s8 { @include animation(smokeL 10s 8s infinite) }
#smoke .s9 { @include animation(smokeR 10s 9s infinite) }
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/verlok/pen/nLsdB)

Comment: [other example](http://mistonline.in/wp/smoke-effect-for-this-christmas-and-newyear-using-javascript-jquery-css/), [and other](http://dhirajkumarsingh.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/animated-smoke-effect-hot-coffee-tea-jquery-css/)

Answer (score 0):

Using one large animated background seems like a bad idea.  The image file will always be large, and take a long time to load.

Can you break up the large background into parts, and animate those individual parts?  Something like this:

http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/pure-css3-animated-clouds-background

The basic idea behind it is simple. Each cloud is placed inside it's own div element.  Usually it contains a png image with a transparent background.

Then you can using a combination of css and jQuery.  The element can be animated to give the look of a large moving background.

Answer (score 0):

With CSS3 animations, you can move objects wherever you like:
*[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tpahadi/3X5yW/)*

```
#smoke {
    -webkit-animation: myAnimation 20s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: myAnimation 20s;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-2;/* ForBackground*/
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes myAnimation {
    0% {top:0; left:0}
    25% {top:10%; left:10%}
    50% {top:20%; left:25%}
    100% {top:15%; left:10%}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes myAnimation {
    0% {top:0; left:0}
    25% {top:10%; left:10%}
    50% {top:20%; left:25%}
    100% {top:15%; left:10%}
}
```

You can change the `0%, 25%, 50%, 100%` for any number and change the `time  of animation` as well as `position`. That might help you out.